# Ошибка в отсутствии конструктора

Tags: java, android, xml, ооп, activity

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.karsa.infection/com.example.karsa.infection.MainMenu$Information}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class has no zero argument constructor
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2361)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>       Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class has no zero argument constructor
>          at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>          at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

код класса:

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public MainMenu(){super();}
public void Infor(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, Information.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public City Cities[]=new City[48];
public int LTInfected[]=new int[10];
public byte orient=0;
public boolean GrMed=false;
public boolean ReMed=false;
public boolean BlMed=false;
public boolean WhMed=false;
public boolean Win=false;
public Player P=new Player();
```

//TODO

```
void OnCreate(){
    Cities[0]=new City(0,new int[4],"Сан-Франциско",false);
    Cities[0].ConWith[0]=1;
    Cities[0].ConWith[1]=12;
    Cities[0].ConWith[2]=46;
    Cities[0].ConWith[3]=44;
    Cities[1]=new City(1,new int[5],"Чикаго",false);
    Cities[1].ConWith[0]=0;
    Cities[1].ConWith[1]=12;
    Cities[1].ConWith[2]=13;
    Cities[1].ConWith[3]=2;
    Cities[1].ConWith[4]=3;
    Cities[2]=new City(2,new int[3],"Атланта",true);
    Cities[2].ConWith[0]=1;
    Cities[2].ConWith[1]=17;
    Cities[2].ConWith[2]=4;
    Cities[3]=new City(3,new int[3],"Монреаль",false);
    Cities[3].ConWith[0]=1;
    Cities[3].ConWith[1]=4;
    Cities[3].ConWith[2]=5;
    Cities[4]=new City(4,new int[4],"Вашигтон",false);
    Cities[4].ConWith[0]=2;
    Cities[4].ConWith[1]=12;
    Cities[4].ConWith[2]=3;
    Cities[4].ConWith[3]=5;
    Cities[5]=new City(5,new int[4],"Нью-Йорк",false);
    Cities[5].ConWith[0]=7;
    Cities[5].ConWith[1]=6;
    Cities[5].ConWith[2]=3;
    Cities[5].ConWith[3]=4;
    Cities[6]=new City(6,new int[4],"Мадрид",false);
    Cities[6].ConWith[0]=19;
    Cities[6].ConWith[1]=5;
    Cities[6].ConWith[2]=7;
    Cities[6].ConWith[3]=8;
    Cities[6].ConWith[4]=24;
    Cities[7]=new City(7,new int[4],"Лондон",false);
    Cities[7].ConWith[0]=5;
    Cities[7].ConWith[1]=6;
    Cities[7].ConWith[2]=8;
    Cities[7].ConWith[3]=9;
    Cities[8]=new City(8,new int[5],"Париж",false);
    Cities[8].ConWith[0]=24;
    Cities[8].ConWith[1]=6;
    Cities[8].ConWith[2]=9;
    Cities[8].ConWith[3]=10;
    Cities[8].ConWith[4]=7;
    Cities[9]=new City(9,new int[4],"Эссен",false);
    Cities[9].ConWith[0]=7;
    Cities[9].ConWith[1]=8;
    Cities[9].ConWith[2]=10;
    Cities[9].ConWith[3]=11;
    Cities[10]=new City(10,new int[3],"Милан",false);
    Cities[10].ConWith[0]=9;
    Cities[10].ConWith[1]=8;
    Cities[10].ConWith[2]=26;
    Cities[11]=new City(11,new int[3],"Санкт-Петербург",false);
    Cities[11].ConWith[0]=9;
    Cities[11].ConWith[1]=26;
    Cities[11].ConWith[2]=28;
    Cities[12]=new City(12,new int[4],"Лос Анджелес",false);
    Cities[12].ConWith[0]=45;
    Cities[12].ConWith[1]=13;
    Cities[12].ConWith[2]=0;
    Cities[12].ConWith[3]=1;
    Cities[13]=new City(13,new int[5],"Мехико",false);
    Cities[13].ConWith[0]=12;
    Cities[13].ConWith[1]=1;
    Cities[13].ConWith[2]=17;
    Cities[13].ConWith[3]=16;
    Cities[13].ConWith[4]=14;
    Cities[14]=new City(14,new int[3],"Лима",false);
    Cities[14].ConWith[0]=15;
    Cities[14].ConWith[1]=13;
    Cities[14].ConWith[2]=16;
    Cities[15]=new City(15,new int[1],"Сантьяго",false);
    Cities[15].ConWith[0]=14;
    Cities[16]=new City(16,new int[5],"Богота",false);
    Cities[16].ConWith[0]=14;
    Cities[16].ConWith[1]=17;
    Cities[16].ConWith[2]=13;
    Cities[16].ConWith[3]=18;
    Cities[16].ConWith[4]=19;
    Cities[17]=new City(17,new int[3],"Майами",false);
    Cities[17].ConWith[0]=2;
    Cities[17].ConWith[1]=4;
    Cities[17].ConWith[2]=16;
    Cities[17].ConWith[3]=13;
    Cities[18]=new City(18,new int[2],"Буэнос-Айрес",false);
    Cities[18].ConWith[0]=16;
    Cities[18].ConWith[1]=19;
    Cities[19]=new City(19,new int[4],"Сан-Пауло",false);
    Cities[19].ConWith[0]=18;
    Cities[19].ConWith[1]=6;
    Cities[19].ConWith[2]=20;
    Cities[19].ConWith[3]=16;
    Cities[20]=new City(20,new int[3],"Лагос",false);
    Cities[20].ConWith[0]=19;
    Cities[20].ConWith[1]=21;
    Cities[20].ConWith[2]=23;
    Cities[21]=new City(21,new int[3],"Киншаса",false);
    Cities[21].ConWith[0]=20;
    Cities[21].ConWith[1]=23;
    Cities[21].ConWith[2]=22;
    Cities[22]=new City(22,new int[2],"Йоханнесбург",false);
    Cities[22].ConWith[0]=21;
    Cities[22].ConWith[1]=23;
    Cities[23]=new City(23,new int[4],"Хартум",false);
    Cities[23].ConWith[0]=25;
    Cities[23].ConWith[1]=20;
    Cities[23].ConWith[2]=21;
    Cities[23].ConWith[3]=22;
    Cities[24]=new City(24,new int[4],"Алжир",false);
    Cities[24].ConWith[0]=8;
    Cities[24].ConWith[1]=6;
    Cities[24].ConWith[2]=26;
    Cities[24].ConWith[3]=25;
    Cities[25]=new City(25,new int[5],"Каир",false);
    Cities[25].ConWith[0]=26;
    Cities[25].ConWith[1]=29;
    Cities[25].ConWith[2]=27;
    Cities[25].ConWith[3]=23;
    Cities[25].ConWith[4]=24;
    Cities[26]=new City(26,new int[6],"Стамбул",false);
    Cities[26].ConWith[0]=25;
    Cities[26].ConWith[1]=24;
    Cities[26].ConWith[2]=10;
    Cities[26].ConWith[3]=11;
    Cities[26].ConWith[4]=28;
    Cities[26].ConWith[5]=17;
    Cities[27]=new City(27,new int[5],"Багдад",false);
    Cities[27].ConWith[0]=25;
    Cities[27].ConWith[1]=26;
    Cities[27].ConWith[2]=30;
    Cities[27].ConWith[3]=29;
    Cities[27].ConWith[4]=31;
    Cities[28]=new City(28,new int[3],"Москва",false);
    Cities[28].ConWith[0]=26;
    Cities[28].ConWith[1]=11;
    Cities[28].ConWith[2]=30;
    Cities[29]=new City(29,new int[4],"Эр-Рияд",false);
    Cities[29].ConWith[0]=25;
    Cities[29].ConWith[1]=27;
    Cities[29].ConWith[2]=31;
    Cities[30]=new City(30,new int[4],"Тегеран",false);
    Cities[30].ConWith[0]=28;
    Cities[30].ConWith[1]=27;
    Cities[30].ConWith[2]=33;
    Cities[30].ConWith[3]=32;
    Cities[31]=new City(31,new int[5],"Карачи",false);
    Cities[31].ConWith[0]=33;
    Cities[31].ConWith[1]=29;
    Cities[31].ConWith[2]=32;
    Cities[31].ConWith[3]=27;
    Cities[31].ConWith[4]=30;
    Cities[32]=new City(32,new int[3],"Мумбаи",false);
    Cities[32].ConWith[0]=31;
    Cities[32].ConWith[1]=33;
    Cities[32].ConWith[2]=34;
    Cities[33]=new City(33,new int[5],"Дели",false);
    Cities[33].ConWith[0]=30;
    Cities[33].ConWith[1]=31;
    Cities[33].ConWith[2]=32;
    Cities[33].ConWith[3]=34;
    Cities[33].ConWith[4]=35;
    Cities[34]=new City(34,new int[5],"Ченнаи",false);
    Cities[34].ConWith[0]=33;
    Cities[34].ConWith[1]=35;
    Cities[34].ConWith[2]=36;
    Cities[34].ConWith[3]=37;
    Cities[34].ConWith[4]=21;
    Cities[35]=new City(35,new int[4],"Калькутта",false);
    Cities[35].ConWith[0]=33;
    Cities[35].ConWith[1]=34;
    Cities[35].ConWith[2]=36;
    Cities[35].ConWith[3]=40;
    Cities[36]=new City(36,new int[5],"Бангкок",false);
    Cities[36].ConWith[0]=34;
    Cities[36].ConWith[1]=33;
    Cities[36].ConWith[2]=37;
    Cities[36].ConWith[3]=40;
    Cities[36].ConWith[4]=41;
    Cities[37]=new City(37,new int[4],"Джакарта",false);
    Cities[37].ConWith[0]=36;
    Cities[37].ConWith[1]=34;
    Cities[37].ConWith[2]=41;
    Cities[37].ConWith[3]=45;
    Cities[38]=new City(38,new int[2],"Пекин",false);
    Cities[38].ConWith[0]=42;
    Cities[38].ConWith[1]=39;
    Cities[39]=new City(39,new int[5],"Шанхай",false);
    Cities[39].ConWith[0]=38;
    Cities[39].ConWith[1]=42;
    Cities[39].ConWith[2]=46;
    Cities[39].ConWith[3]=40;
    Cities[39].ConWith[4]=43;
    Cities[40]=new City(40,new int[6],"Гонконг",false);
    Cities[40].ConWith[0]=39;
    Cities[40].ConWith[1]=43;
    Cities[40].ConWith[2]=44;
    Cities[40].ConWith[3]=41;
    Cities[40].ConWith[4]=36;
    Cities[40].ConWith[5]=35;
    Cities[41]=new City(41,new int[4],"Хошимин",false);
    Cities[41].ConWith[0]=36;
    Cities[41].ConWith[1]=37;
    Cities[41].ConWith[2]=40;
    Cities[41].ConWith[3]=44;
    Cities[42]=new City(42,new int[3],"Сеул",false);
    Cities[42].ConWith[0]=38;
    Cities[42].ConWith[1]=46;
    Cities[42].ConWith[2]=39;
    Cities[43]=new City(43,new int[4],"Тайбэй",false);
    Cities[43].ConWith[0]=39;
    Cities[43].ConWith[1]=46;
    Cities[43].ConWith[2]=40;
    Cities[43].ConWith[3]=44;
    Cities[44]=new City(44,new int[5],"Манила",false);
    Cities[44].ConWith[0]=41;
    Cities[44].ConWith[1]=43;
    Cities[44].ConWith[2]=40;
    Cities[44].ConWith[3]=45;
    Cities[44].ConWith[4]=0;
    Cities[45]=new City(45,new int[3],"Сидней",false);
    Cities[45].ConWith[0]=12;
    Cities[45].ConWith[1]=37;
    Cities[45].ConWith[2]=44;
    Cities[46]=new City(46,new int[4],"Токио",false);
    Cities[46].ConWith[0]=0;
    Cities[46].ConWith[1]=42;
    Cities[46].ConWith[2]=39;
    Cities[46].ConWith[3]=47;
    Cities[47]=new City(47,new int[2],"Оскака",false);
    Cities[47].ConWith[0]=46;
    Cities[47].ConWith[1]=43;
}
int[][] Infector(int INumber){
    int[][] Ret=new int[INumber][2];
    for (int p=0;p<INumber;p++){
        int gen=InfGen(false);
        Ret[p][1]=gen;
        int tp=InfGen(true);
        Ret[p][tp]=tp;
    }
    return Ret;
}
int InfGen(boolean type){

    Random rand = new Random();
    if(type){
        return rand.nextInt(4);
    }
    else {
        int Inf=rand.nextInt(48);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            if(Inf==LTInfected[i]){
                Inf=InfGen(false);
            }

        }
        LTInfected[orient]=Inf;
        if(orient==9){
            orient=0;
        }
        else {
            orient++;
        }
        return Inf;


    }

}

class Player {
    int Position;
    int FinPoints;
    int RExp;
    int GExp;
    int BExp;
    int WExp;
    public Player(){}
    void onCreate(){
        this.Position=2;
        this.FinPoints=0;
        this.RExp=0;
        this.GExp=0;
        this.BExp=0;
        this.WExp=0;

    }
    void DoMed(int type){
        switch (type) {
            case 0:
                this.RExp-=10;
                ReMed=true;
                break;
            case 1:
                this.GExp-=10;
                GrMed=true;
                break;
            case 2:
                this.BExp-=10;
                BlMed=true;
                break;
            case 3:
                this.WExp-=10;
                WhMed=true;
                break;
        }
        if(ReMed&GrMed&BlMed&WhMed) Win=true;
    }
    void GetExp(int type){
        this.FinPoints-=2;
        switch (type){
            case 0:
                Cities[Position].Red--;
                this.RExp+=1;
                break;
            case 1:
                Cities[Position].Green--;
                this.GExp+=1;
                break;
            case 2:
                Cities[Position].Blue--;
                this.BExp+=1;
                break;
            case 3:
                Cities[Position].White--;
                this.WExp+=1;
                break;




        }
    }
    void stat(){
        this.FinPoints-=3;
        Cities[this.Position].BStation();
    }

    void ChPos(int nPosition){
        boolean check=false;
        for(int i=0;i<Cities[Position].ConWith.length;i++){
            if (nPosition==Cities[Position].ConWith[i]) {
                check=true;
                this.Position=nPosition;
            }

        }
        if (check==false){
            this.FinPoints-=3;
            this.Position=nPosition;
        }

    }


}
class City {
    int Red;
    int Green;
    int Blue;
    int White;
    int id;
    int ConWith[];
    String Name;
    boolean Station;
    public City(){}

    public City(int id,int ConWith[], String Name,boolean Station)
    {

        this.id=id;
        this.Red=0;
        this.Green=0;
        this.Blue=0;
        this.White=0;
        this.ConWith=ConWith;
        this.Name=Name;
        this.Station=Station;


    }
    public void Cure(int type) {
        switch (type) {
            case 0:
                if(ReMed==false){
                    P.FinPoints++;
                    this.Red -= 1;
                }
                else{
                    P.FinPoints+=this.Red;
                    this.Red=0;

                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if(GrMed==false){
                    P.FinPoints++;
                    this.Green -= 1;
                }
                else{
                    P.FinPoints+=this.Green;
                    this.Green=0;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(BlMed==false){
                    P.FinPoints++;
                    this.Blue -= 1;
                }
                else{
                    P.FinPoints+=this.Blue;
                    this.Blue=0;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(WhMed==false){
                    P.FinPoints++;
                    this.White -= 1;
                }
                else{
                    P.FinPoints+=this.White;
                    this.White=0;
                }
                break;

        }

    }
    public void CureAll(int type)
    {
        switch(type){
            case 0:
                P.FinPoints+=this.Red;
                this.Red=0;
                break;
            case 1:
                P.FinPoints+=this.Green;
                this.Green=0;
                break;
            case 2:
                P.FinPoints+=this.Blue;
                this.Blue=0;
                break;
            case 3:
                P.FinPoints+=this.White;
                this.White=0;
                break;

        }
    }
    public void BStation()
    {
        this.Station=true;

    }


}
public class Information extends Activity {


public Information(){super();}
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_information);
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText(
                    "Алжир: R-"+Cities[24].Red+"; G-"+Cities[24].Green+"; B-"+Cities[24].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[24].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Багдад: R-"+Cities[28].Red+"; G-"+Cities[28].Green+"; B-"+Cities[28].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[28].White+"\n"+
                            "Бангкок: R-"+Cities[36].Red+"; G-"+Cities[36].Green+"; B-"+Cities[36].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[36].White+"\n"+
                            "Богота: R-"+Cities[16].Red+"; G-"+Cities[16].Green+"; B-"+Cities[16].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[16].White+"\n"+
                            "Буэнос-Айрес: R-"+Cities[18].Red+"; G-"+Cities[18].Green+"; B-"+Cities[18].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[18].White+"\n"+
                            "Вашингтон: R-"+Cities[4].Red+"; G-"+Cities[4].Green+"; B-"+Cities[4].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[4].White+"\n"+
                            "Гонконг: R-"+Cities[40].Red+"; G-"+Cities[40].Green+"; B-"+Cities[40].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[40].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n"+
                            "Атланта: R-"+Cities[2].Red+"; G-"+Cities[2].Green+"; B-"+Cities[2].Blue+"; W-"+Cities[2].White+"\n");

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Добавьте ясности в вопрос. Где именно не получается, какая ошибка.

Comment: Самый первый "код" это ошибка

Comment: Вопрос должен содержать [mcve]. Сейчас это больше похоже на тест способностей дистанционной отладки.

Comment: из приведенного кода не очень видно (кода много, и форматирование поплыло), но похоже у вас класс `Information` является внутренним (inner) классом `MainActivity`. Для внутренних классов компилятор дополняет все конструкторы аргументом, в который при создании передается экземпляр класса верхнего уровня, поэтому у `Information` нет конструктора без параметров, и фреймворк не может создать его экземпляр. Вам надо либо сделать `Information` классом верхнего уровня (в отдельном файле), или объявить `static`. При этом у вас возникнет проблема с передачей состояния (`Cities`), но это другой вопрос.

Comment: Когда подскажите как получить информацию, именно по это причине он занесен как класс внутренний

Comment: ну я бы начал с выноса всех данных и кода по игре из активити в отдельный класс (модель игры), чтобы в активити только вызывать методы модели в ответ на действия пользователя. Дальше объект с текущей игрой можно хранить где-то в статической переменной или поле наследника `Application` (но это небезопасно), или сохранять в shared preference (например сериализовав в json)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ в сообщении об ошибке - нема в супер классе конструктора с нулём параметров, а он вызывается в конструкторе приведённого класса активити. Надо просто удалить конструктор в активити. В активити он вообще не нужен.